# next-auth only valid absolute URLs can be requested

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, next-auth, okta-signin-widget

I updated `next-auth@3.23.3` to `next-auth@4.3.2` for okta signin(reactjs). After that I am getting the following errors:

```
[next-auth][error][SIGNIN_OAUTH_ERROR] https://next-auth.js.org/errors#signin_oauth_error only valid absolute URLs can be requested
```

Please anyone help me get out of this.

Comment: If you go to the [link](https://next-auth.js.org/errors#signin_oauth_error) provided in your error, you will get some clues about it, but without any code it's very hard to help you deeply, so please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Another difference... the domain has to include https://

Comment: You can share this as a comment!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that after you upgrade from `next-auth` v3 to v4, you also update the config object you're passing to `OktaProvider`.

The problem with me is that I was still using `domain` while the new API was expecting `issuer`.

v3:

```js
OktaProvider({
  clientId: data.REACT_APP_OKTA_CLIENTID,
  clientSecret: data.REACT_APP_OKTA_CLIENTSECRET,
  domain: data.REACT_APP_OKTA_DOMAIN, // <<<<<<<<<< before
}),
```

v4:

```js
OktaProvider({
  clientId: data.REACT_APP_OKTA_CLIENTID,
  clientSecret: data.REACT_APP_OKTA_CLIENTSECRET,
  issuer: data.REACT_APP_OKTA_DOMAIN, // <<<<<<<<<< after
}),
```

Comment: This is also the case with other providers, for example Auth0
And make sure issuer field includes not only domain name but also protocol e.g. https://

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your okta issuer looks like this:

https://{your_okta_domain}.okta.com/oauth2/default

Also if you are using it in localhost, in your .env file make sure that you store this variable without enclosing it in "". So instead of storing the value as:

OKTA_ISSUER = "my_okta_issuer"

use instead:

OKTA_ISSUER = my_okta_issuer

It took me a day to figure that out, but now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you missed a step when upgrading, I suggest you (re-)visit the [update guide](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/upgrade-v4)

The description you provided is very minimal, making it hard to give you a valuable answer. If you share your codebase somehow, either via GitHub, a sandbox, or a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the community can help you better